# Finding stream url from SHL Play

Tags: url, stream

I've tried everything to find the stream urls from SHL Play, for example http://play.shl.se/video/12460620/. I've only managed to download some MP4:s that are actually still pictures working as a cover before you press play.

/Oscar

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself, using Internet Download Manager =)